# Cannot read file from Internal root storage

Tags: android

I have a rooted Android Phone and my Client has 8 Tablets (Unrooted). They will be using it tomorrow night to do some contest judging from Android Tablet. I have made an app that reads files from the custom folder on root folder of my Internal Memory which runs fine on my rooted mobile but not on Clients Unrooted Tablets.

According to them all the files will be upto 3GB stored in the Internal Memory. I' am stuck guys really need help and advise what should I do?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView welcomeLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeLogo);
        welcomeLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.iba);

        //Get the text file
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        File file = new File(dir, "lvi/names.txt");
        //Read text from file
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();

            //Find the view by its id
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.welcomeJudge);
            //Set the text
            tv.setText("Welcome " + text.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //You'll need to add proper error handling here
        }

        //When the enter button is click goto the dashboard activity
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent dashboardIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, dashboard.class);
                startActivity(dashboardIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Permissions on my Manifests**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Are you trying to read files from internal storage? You're using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: @badjr Yes from an internal storage

Comment: @badjr is correct, you are not using internal storage and second thing is if client tablets API level is 23 or above, they might be getting `SecurityException` because of permissions. Are they getting any crash or something? Please elaborate.

Comment: @GauravChauhan `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()); File file = new File(dir, "lvi/names.txt");` give me `/storage/emulated/0/ibm/judge.txt`

Comment: @DevilRaily What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Android 6.0 (API level 23) you have to set runtime permission

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((BaseActivity) context,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_AND_WRITE_SDK);
    } else {
        ReadMethod();//your custom method 


    }
```

onRequestPermissionsResult

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

switch (requestCode) {
    case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_AND_WRITE_SDK:

        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ReadMethod();//your custom method 
        }
        break;


    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @sasikumar please can you explain more. Where should I paste this codes? Thanks!

Comment: Before  perform the action its ask permission in android 6 based on result it will work..refer for more details https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: what is the ReadMethod();

Comment: that is your custom method